# Using DATEDIFF in WHERE clause Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query in SQL

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(DD,[fld_DateResolved],GETDATE()) > 3
```

What I want to do is, to close tickets after 3 Days in my System, My question is, is this the correct way to query to check if the DATEDIFF of DateResolved and GetDate is Greater than 3?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, your approach is very right.

Comment: Greater than 3 days or Greater than 72 hours ? If it is 3 complete days, i'd suggest the approach by @MitchWheat and modify it with CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE).

Comment: It's okay, except that you've now destroyed any chance of using an index on the column. This probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make it S'argable (which means an appropriate index might be used if it exists):

```
WHERE [fld_DateResolved] <= DATEADD(Day, -3, CAST(GETDATE() as Date))
```

[Updated: added a cast to `Date` which assumes you are on SQL Server 2008+]

Comment: Now it gets Tickets that should not be closed after 3 days.

Comment: I think you intended `DATEADD` here, not `DATEDIFF`.

Comment: bugger! thx.!...Updated. was busy talking to my boss and got distracted! :)

Comment: Thanks I think it worked, I hope! But i'm getting my desired result